# Colour according to custom values in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have a list of values x and y and wanted to create a 2D heatmap. In this case, x = "values_Rot" and y = "values_Tilt".

Using matplotlib, I generated the heatmap with the 'jet' colour scheme. In this default coloring scheme, I want to change this map, which looks as if as most of the data are in the dark blue side. Is there a way to manually edit the default colouring scheme?

Say, you want to change dark blue to represent values 0-10, cyan to represent 10-25, yellow to represent 15-20 and 30-50 is red. Also, in this case, we would like to stick to 'jet' colour scheme, which is a gradient.

Is there an easy way of putting the custom values for this heatmap?

I have attached the image of the heatmap. A part of the raw_data.star file in case you want to refer.

The code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

file_name = '/home/run_data.star'

raw = open(file_name, 'r')

input_data = raw.readlines()

raw.close()

headers = []
loops = []
data = []

for line in input_data:
    if line[0:3] in '_rln':
        tup = (line.split()[0], line.split()[1]);
        headers.append(tup)
    elif line[0:5] in ['data_','loop_']:
        loops.append(line)
    elif line[0] in ['\n']:
        pass
    else:
        data.append(line)

AngleRot = '_rlnAngleRot'
AngleTilt= '_rlnAngleTilt'
AnglePsi = '_rlnAnglePsi'

# This returns the ***pythonic*** column number (ie starting at 0)

def get_header_number(list_of_headers, column):
    for header in list_of_headers:
        if header[0] in column:
            return (   int(  (header[1])[1:]  ) -1  )   

rot_number = get_header_number(headers, AngleRot)
tilt_number = get_header_number(headers, AngleTilt)
psi_number = get_header_number(headers, AnglePsi)

values_Rot = []
values_Tilt = []
values_Psi = []

for line in data:
    try:
        values_Rot.append(float(line.split()[rot_number]))
        values_Tilt.append(float(line.split()[tilt_number]))
        values_Psi.append(float(line.split()[psi_number]))

    except:
        print ('This line didnt work, it may just be a blank space. The line is:' + line)

# Change the values here if you want to plot something else, such as psi. 
# You can also change how the data is binned here.
plt.hist2d(values_Rot, values_Tilt, bins=100,)
plt.set_cmap('jet')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()


plt.savefig('name_of_output.png')
```

A portion of the raw file - data.star.

```
# version 30001

data_optics

loop_ 
_rlnOpticsGroup #1 
_rlnOpticsGroupName #2 
_rlnAmplitudeContrast #3 
_rlnSphericalAberration #4 
_rlnVoltage #5 
_rlnImagePixelSize #6 
_rlnImageSize #7 
_rlnImageDimensionality #8 
_rlnCtfDataAreCtfPremultiplied #9 
_rlnMagMat00 #10 
_rlnMagMat01 #11 
_rlnMagMat10 #12 
_rlnMagMat11 #13 
           1 opticsGroup1     0.100000     2.700000   300.000000     1.070000          600            2            0     1.000740 6.259422e-05 1.017571e-05     0.999216 
           2 opticsGroup2     0.100000     2.700000   300.000000     1.070000          600            2            0     1.000639 7.726579e-06 -3.12840e-05     0.999596 
 

# version 30001

data_particles

loop_ 
_rlnCoordinateX #1 
_rlnCoordinateY #2 
_rlnImageName #3 
_rlnMicrographName #4 
_rlnCtfMaxResolution #5 
_rlnCtfFigureOfMerit #6 
_rlnDefocusU #7 
_rlnDefocusV #8 
_rlnDefocusAngle #9 
_rlnCtfBfactor #10 
_rlnCtfScalefactor #11 
_rlnPhaseShift #12 
_rlnAngleRot #13 
_rlnAngleTilt #14 
_rlnAnglePsi #15 
_rlnClassNumber #16 
_rlnNormCorrection #17 
_rlnRandomSubset #18 
_rlnLogLikeliContribution #19 
_rlnMaxValueProbDistribution #20 
_rlnNrOfSignificantSamples #21 
_rlnGroupName #22 
_rlnOpticsGroup #23 
_rlnOriginXAngst #24 
_rlnOriginYAngst #25 
_rlnGroupNumber #26 
_rlnImageOriginalName #27 
 1788.000000  2851.000000 000001@Subtract/job1828/Particles/subtracted_rank1_opticsgroup1.mrcs MotionCorr/job002/Micrographs/20190717_1142-235822.mrc     5.706667     0.118566 29144.182377 29316.629233    86.986818     0.000000     1.000000     0.000000    -56.39558   140.725020   -100.20771            1     1.699107            2 1.335631e+06     0.560834            6   group_11            1    16.018157     1.038157            1 1@Polish/job1441/Micrographs/20190717_1142-235822_shiny.mrcs 
 1853.000000  3245.000000 000002@Subtract/job1828/Particles/subtracted_rank1_opticsgroup1.mrcs MotionCorr/job002/Micrographs/20190717_1143-235823.mrc     5.447273     0.143154 23501.419886 23574.563921    99.812734     0.000000     1.000000     0.000000   -125.52943    41.225613   -172.41409            1     1.691859            2 1.336149e+06     0.278960            8   group_19            1    -16.08184     -0.66983            2 1@Polish/job1441/Micrographs/20190717_1143-235823_shiny.mrcs 
 2873.000000  3523.000000 000003@Subtract/job1828/Particles/subtracted_rank1_opticsgroup1.mrcs MotionCorr/job002/Micrographs/20190717_1143-235823.mrc     5.447273     0.143154 23501.419886 23574.563921    99.812734     0.000000     1.000000     0.000000     7.731781    47.134914    -37.31431            1     1.709648            2 1.335800e+06     0.174313           11   group_19            1     3.178157    -12.87184            2 2@Polish/job1441/Micrographs/20190717_1143-235823_shiny.mrcs 
  942.000000  1797.000000 000001@Subtract/job1828/Particles/subtracted_rank2_opticsgroup1.mrcs MotionCorr/job002/Micrographs/20190717_1145-235824.mrc     4.858379     0.148493 18280.070841 18428.337564   103.335158     0.000000     1.000000     0.000000    -54.88750   145.342189   -178.92586            1     1.701785            1 1.335641e+06     0.359985            2   group_11            1     3.178157    16.018157            1 1@Polish/job1441/Micrographs/20190717_1145-235824_shiny.mrcs
```

Comment: Colormaps and their use is very flexible in matplotlib. You can edit them, make your own, etc. It would be very helpful if you could write a question that was short and clear, especially with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Note that the 'jet' colormap isn't a gradient, it has a bright yellow region which is not at the extreme. [It's recomended to be avoided.](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/). For more appropriate colormaps, see [this doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).